# Stored procedures are getting locked

Tags: sql-server, concurrency

I have some procedures which use SQL statements like these:

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SymKey_Xyz DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Certificate_Xyz
SELECT DECRYPTBYKEY(column1),DECRYPTBYKEY(column1) from ABC
CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY SymKey_Xyz
```

When these procedures are executed for more than 500 users concurrently, the system is locking these procedures.

Is there any better approach to use Encryption/Decryption in SQL Server which will not impact performance so much?

Comment: What algorithm is the symmetric key? `select name, algorithm_desc from sys.symmetric_keys`

Comment: We are using AES_256 encryption.

Comment: Are you sure it's encryption and another insert/update query which is causing the lockup? Can you share the query plan via https://pastetheplan.com